# It is possible to do operations with Roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I put the Role `[Authorize Roles (Role.Administrator, Role.Assistant)]`, is an **OR** or **AND** or you can not do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put an `[Authorize]`attribute on a controller or action you are saying the user must be in one of those roles.

Think of it more like 'Authorize using this controller or action if this user is in roleA or roleB'